# What features would a creature that could see radio waves have?

Tags: science-based, biology, vision

What physically apparent features and what organs would a creature that could see radio waves have to have?

Comment: Eyes a metre wide, for starters.  The comments in [this question](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/249393/an-eye-that-can-see-all-the-electromagnetic-spectrum-from-gamma-rays-to-radio-wa) should indicate some of the problems involved in "seeing" radio.

Comment: What a strange decision it is, to close a question as a duplicate of one that was itself closed for being too broad, when the new question is a significantly narrower version of it. It is hardly a duplicate in the first place, and the differences directly address the problem that got its (non) "duplicate" closed. I will never fully understand the moderation of this site...

Comment: The biggest problem here is how an ability to detect radio waves may evolve. There is no natural source of such wavelengths in a reasonable habitable world, so such ability doesn't seem to offer any evolutionary advantage; the burden, on the other hand, is quite high.